# How to add two odd lists into one list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am very new to Python, and I'm trying to combine elements from two lists and produce a string from the combination.

My variables are:

```
fro = ['USD']
to = ['AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR']
```

I want output like this in a string:

```
pairs = "USDAUD,USDCAD,USDEUR"
```

Thanks a ton in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Elizion is absolutely correct.

If you have list elements varies dynamically, you can use this line:

absolutely pythonic way!!

```
pair_elem = ','.join('%s%s' % (x, y) for y in to for x in fro)
```

And conventional way is like, iterate list elems:

```
for multiple in to:
    for single in fro:
        pairs = ",".join(single + multiple)
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) like this:

```
fro = ['USD']
to = ['AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR']
pairs = ','.join(fro[0] + x for x in to)
```

Note that `from` is a reserved keyword and is thus not a valid variable name.

***Output:***

```
>>>pairs
'USDAUD,USDCAD,USDEUR'
```

If you were ever curious as to whether something you wish to use as a variable name is a keyword (*and thus an illegal variable name*) or not, you can always check with something like this:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword("from") 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Elizion's answer is nice and succinct, but as a beginner you may want to approach it without using an intermediate/advanced structure like a generator:

```
fro = ['USD']
to = ['AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR']

pairs = ""

for word in to:
    pairs += fro[0] + word + ","
```

Removing the trailing comma:

```
pairs = pairs[:-1]
```